# How to find the last element in the realm database

Tags: android, realm

In realm we have the option to find the first element in the database using `findFirst()`. But I want to do the reverse of it. I want to last element based on the some condition which I provide.

To find out the first element in the realm database:

```
GamesDetail learnGameDetail = realm.where(GamesDetail.class).equalTo("gameType", getResources().getString(R.string.learn_row)).notEqualTo("currentBadge",0).findFirst();
```

In the above query all the rows will have `currentBadge` as zero. But the last updated row will have `currentBadge` with some value. I need to find the last updated row with `currentBadge` not equal to zero.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realm.io Android best approach to get last 20 items from a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28229866/realm-io-android-best-approach-to-get-last-20-items-from-a-table)

Comment: for better reliability, put timestamp field in realm and query with `order by timestamp desc` and then find first

Comment: Unsorted result sets are not guaranteed to retain order after deletion.

Comment: @V.Y it is not.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
GamesDetail learnGameDetail = realm.where(GamesDetail.class)
        .equalTo("gameType", getResources().getString(R.string.learn_row))
        .notEqualTo("currentBadge",0)
        .findFirst();
```

You can do

```
GamesDetail learnGameDetail = realm.where(GamesDetail.class)
             .equalTo("gameType", getResources().getString(R.string.learn_row))
             .notEqualTo("currentBadge",0)
             .findAll()
             .last(null);
```

Please note that insertion order is **not** kept after deletion. Using `findAllSorted()` is generally advised.